# websocket + vue :get error connecting to websocket

Tags: websocket, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I am beginner with **websocket** and i am trying to connect it with **vue3** like this

```
 onMounted(() => {
  var connection = new WebSocket("wss://echo.websocket.org");
  connection.onopen = function () {
    console.log("Server opened");
  };
});
```

and I get this every time
[image]

**How** can I **fix** this ?

Answer (score 0):

Websocket.org is no longer available.
https://www.lob.com/blog/websocket-org-is-down-here-is-an-alternative